# Ruby: How to create attr_accessor on the fly

Tags: ruby, attributes, attr-accessor

I want to know how to create attr_accessor on the fly. Is it possible to do something like:

```
attr_accessor "@#{key}"
```

inside the initialize method?

```
module Mymodule
  def initialize(parameters = {})
    parameters.each do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) unless value.nil?
    end
  end
end

class Myclass
  include Mymodule
end

clazz = Myclass.new attr1: "Arg1", attr2: "Arg2", attr3: "Arg3"
  # => #<Myclass:0x43f6050 @attr1="Arg1", @attr2="Arg2", @attr3="Arg3">

clazz.attr1
  # !> NoMethodError: undefined method `attr1' for #<Myclass:0x43f6050 @attr1="Arg1", @attr2="Arg2", @attr3="Arg3">

clazz.attr1="ATTR1"
  # !> NoMethodError: undefined method `attr1=' for #<Myclass:0x43f6050 @attr1="Arg1", @attr2="Arg2", @attr3="Arg3">
```

Answer (score 8):

You can define per instance accessors by calling `attr_accessor` on that instance's singleton class.

```
class Structy
  def initialize(parameters = {})
    parameters.each do |key, value|
      singleton_class.send :attr_accessor, key
      instance_variable_set "@#{key}", value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @JulioCarvalho There are also the [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html) and [`OpenStruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) classes in standard Ruby. Often, these classes are helpful to build structs. In any case, you need to be careful with edge-cases here, e.g. when setting special keys like `:hash`, `:to_s` or `:inspect` which can shadow methods you might implicitly rely on to behave like their standard implementation. Check for subtle security issues when allowing user-supplied parameters.

Comment: will not `singleton_class.send :attr_accessor, *parameters.keys` out of `each` loop be more effective?

Comment: @okliv the result would be the same. What do you mean by more "effective"? Performant? If yes, it would barely matter either way.